# I have a golden face, what am I?

Tags: riddle

I have a golden face.
I was Alfred’s present to Albert.
I’m worth more than my weight in gold!
What am I?

Hint: MDCCCXXXIII.
MDCCCXCVI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are

> The Nobel Prize

I have a golden face.

> it does

I was Alfred’s present to Albert

> Alfred Nobel to Albert Einstein

I’m worth more than my weight in gold!

> The cash award and prestige is worth far more than the prizes gold value

And the hint

> Appears on the medal
>   [image]